# Creating new user on OpenSSH windows

Tags: windows, openssh

I installed OpenSSH for windows (2003 server edition), and tried to generate a new user on an OpenSSH server (on which I already managed to log myself on) for a software use purpose, with a password.

So I generated a line on the `passwd` file:

```
johndoe:x:895291:545:JohnDoe Software,johndoe:/cygdrive/c:/bin/bash
```

Where `x` should mean it has to refer to the shadow file for password, right ?
Then I generated a shadow file (*the hash* not the real string, just occluded it for security):

```
johndoe:$1$thehash:16601:0:99999:7::
```

In my `sshd_config` I added the line:

```
AllowUsers johndoe
```

And I restarted the service.
But a wild problem appeared: I could not connect with ssh on the server anymore, even with accounts that could have worked earlier. I won't even speak about the `johndoe`, which doesn't work at all.

I tried to connect on verbose mode with ssh, but nothing particular came up.

I think I'm missing something here, but I can't figure out what... can somebody help me (pretty) please ?

Thanks !